# Adding an xib's view into another view in a storyboard

Tags: ios6, view, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I work in xcode 4.6.2 with ios 6, using arc and storyboards.
I created a MainStoryboard.storyboard
In here I created 2 viewcontrollers: SplashViewController and WalkthroughViewController.
With segues I go from one to the other.
In WalkthroughViewController I created 2 views: 1 scrollview which covers 370 height from top and another view for login module which covers 110 height from bottom.

Now I would like to separate the logic of these two modules.
Because I may reuse the login module and the walkthrough will be a scrollview which will be automated by the images that are in a plist file.

I tried to create a uiviewcontroller called LoginViewController with an xib file and connected the view to my WalkthroughViewController dragging and dropping it to my .h file. I called it loginView. The xib file of the login view has 2 buttons called "facebook login" and "skip login".

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loginView;
```

And in the .m file I tried to initialize this view using the initwithnibname method so:

```
self.loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil].view;
```

The app now works without crashing but the screen is empty.

Any ideas why my view is not being assigned or doesn't seem like it should? I don't see the facebooklogin or skiplogin buttons at all..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to set the frame? something like:

```
self.loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil].view;
CGRect loginViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-110, self.view.frame.size.width, 110);
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    loginView.frame = loginViewFrame;
```

Comment: yes i tried, it seems like i had the iboutlet connected to the view i also created on the walkthroughviewcontroller in storyboard. so it was overriding the code.

Comment: but now i managed to see the view i made in xib. and pressed the button which was there: loginButton. and it crashed giving error: excbadaccess

Comment: i didn't use loginView but used loginViewController as a property of my walkthroughviewcontroller. now i can also access the methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you better not write like this:

```
self.loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil].view;
```

better use whole viewController
like:

```
loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and you can make loginView is viewController not a view
and add- bringSubviewToFront to make loginView visible